# Do not display the content for a webpage for a second

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that refreshes before redirecting (for reasons that are too long to explain) to another page. Is there a way to not show the content on the page that is redirecting with a timer so that the user doesn't get to see a refresh glitch?

It is something like this.

```
Step 1) User goes to page A and clicks on a link.
Step 2) Upon clicking, a set of checks are made (using php) and the user is sent back to page A.
Step 3) After coming back to page A, user is then sent to page B.
```

Steps 2 obviously causes a refresh to occur. I would like after step 1 for the page not to load for a couple of seconds so that step 2 could be not shown to the client (i.e. the refresh).

Comment: Such problems should be solved in your design ASAP. Empty browser window during a few seconds is too bad user experience (I am not downvoter, as educational question this one is good).

Comment: I agree, but it beats a refresh. Plus, something major is loading. They'll live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you're doing is the best way to do it.  But you can hide the contents using the below code

```
function hideAwhile(time){
    var oldDisplay = document.body.style.display;
    document.body.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.display = oldDisplay}, time);
}
```

Comment: I set the time to 5000 and wrapped it in javascript on the top of the page. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: did you call it by using `hideAwhile(5000)`